# Juju manual bootstrap keeps failing

Tags: 16.04, juju

I'm trying to bootstrap a manual cloud by using `juju bootstrap manual/x.x.x.x mycloud` but I keep getting the following warning and afterwards the following error half an hour later. My Public ssh-key is authorized so that is not the issue:

```
2018-01-16 11:51:11 WARNING juju.mongo open.go:159 mongodb connection failed, will retry: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:37017: getsockopt: connection refused 
2018-01-16 12:26:36 WARNING juju.replicaset replicaset.go:122 Initiate: fetching replication status failed: cannot get replica set status: no replset config has been received
```

Are there any Firewall settings that I forgot to change maybe?